# RESTful API returns data when request originates from browser or PHP, but not from JavaScript. Why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make calls to a (private) RESTful web service via a GET request using $jQuery.get(). But when I do, I receive no response data (although I do get a 200 OK response code!).

When I make the exact same call from PHP (file_get_contents()) or just by pasting the GET URL into my browser window, I receive the (JSON) response just fine.

Using Firebug, I can see absolutely no difference between the request headers I'm sending when I make the request from jQuery, and when I paste the URL into my browser. The only difference is that jQuery adds "Referer" and "Origin" headers - *however*, I forcibly added these two headers to my direct browser request using Firefox's ModifyHeaders extension, and I still get the data back, so the service can't be filtering based on Referer/Origin.

So essentially I'm wondering what the hell is going on if I can make two seemingly identical requests but receive no response when it's through jQuery. Is there some "hidden" header or parameter that I'm not seeing which the server can use to determine that the request was sent via JavaScript?

My code is as simple as `$.get("http://example.com/json.php?q=sometext", function(response) { alert(response); });`

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the domain from the link in the `get()` call

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) by trying to send cross domain AJAX requests? If, not make sure that the server sets the proper Content-Type header to `application/json` so that jQuery automatically provides you with a ready to use parsed object in the success callback. Also try passing a relative url to the `$.get` function:

```
$.get("/json.php?q=sometext", function(response) { 
    alert(response); 
});
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to mention this is a remote service. But I've worked with other remote services, calling them straight from jQuery on the page (e.g. YouTube, Flickr APIs) and they work just fine. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @BigJeffrey, if they use JSONP then it is possible. With plain JSON, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get("http://example.com/json.php?q=sometext", 
      function(response) { alert(response); },
      "json");
```

Note last parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. I've also tried using $.getJSON(). Firebug reports "200 OK" but the whole line is in red, and there is a red cross icon next to it - but no note of an error or anything (just a blank response body).